# how to connect report manager url in reporting service configuration manager?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have been trying to connect a report manager to the url `http:\\pc14:8080\report` but it is asking username and password I don't  know which one I have to enter.

After giving some password randomly I see one error page on asp .net.

Please help me to solve this...

I have attached two images with this post please check it and give me solution like which username password and what it that authentication error?

[image: image_1]

[image: image_2]

Comment: The error message says your access is denied. Ask someone around for the right information so you can login.

StackOverflow is not Anonymous, nor is it website hacking community for that matter.

Comment: enter your pc14 server logain credential (username and password).

Comment: I given my pc login credentials but still it raises error.

Comment: where is your sql server installation located means in which pc ?

Comment: I have installed on pc14 machine.